# Automatically decrypt and run an encrypted bash script without saving decrypted file to file system

Tags: bash, encryption, gnupg

I have a shell script that produces sensitive content when run. It sits on a box that only a few users have permissions to access. However, I have also added layered obfuscation to prevent unauthorized usage, via the following:

1. script must be run as root
2. script must be passed specific command line arguments to produce any output
3. script has been encoded by the shell compiler "[shc](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/)" to mask facts #1 and #2 from normal users (those who would not know to use TRACE or STRINGS to still view the actual code).

To then add a layer of actual security to protect again more advanced users and system admins, I have also encrypted the script with gpg.

My question is -- Is there a gpg command (or other encryption method) that I could run which prompts for the decryption passphrase, and decrypts the script and runs it in memory only (without saving the decrypted version of the file to the file system)?

I realize that sensitive information may still exist in unprotected memory while being executed, I'll address that separately.

Comment: Create a small ramdisk, format it, mount it, save the file there, execute it, format the ramdisk, free the ramdisk. But I must ask... is this level of protection *really* necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture the output of decrypting by

```
decrypted=$(gpg -d ...)
```

You can then eval the result

```
eval "$decrypted"
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was able to get this to work only after removing the command line argument requirements from the encrypted script.

I don't know why I didn't think of capturing the output of the command into a variable! 

I probably don't need to keep the argument requirements, but my guess is I have to adjust the syntax in the eval command if I wanted to put them back in.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option to contrast with choroba's answer:

Save the decrypted output to a file in `/dev/shm/`. (It's an in-ram tmpfs filesystem there by default on virtually all Linux distros.) Setup a `trap` to delete the file when your script exits.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible I could refine this, but here's another idea where you execute the script rather than evaluate it like in choroba's example. It allows you to pass arguments...

```
bash <( gpg -d ... ) arg1 arg2
```

...it 'overrides' the interpreter, though. I.e. I'd run my scripts with `bash -ue`. May or may not be a problem depending on the scripts and whether you are writing them yourself or not :)